# "Directory" for the main board in an airport, etc., informing people on arrivals/departures, floors/levels to certain stores, etc

Tags: american-english, vocabulary, word-usage

In AE, is it appropriate to designate as a "directory" the main information board found in the concourse or front room of a public place such as a passenger station, an airport, a shopping mall, an hospital, a movie theater, etc. -- and assisting people in finding various information like arrivals and departures, tracks, gates, levels/floors to certain sections/offices/departments, etc.? 
Or, is there another name (or other names) by it?

If indeed it is, why then can't I seem to find one single dictionary online in which "directory" is defined as such?

If I hadn't already come across this term used in that specific sense, there would be no authoritative source online to state it as fact.

Comment: Yes to everything except the movie theater information board, which, because I need to remember its name is a blank to me. Someone more clear-headed than I will answer, I hope.

Comment: @Susan Actually, I'm asking the question because I can't seem to find a dictionary online that defines a "directory" as such.

Comment: Hmm. Hospitals definitely have directories (google hospital directory and you'll even see pictures)... Airport directory will get you a bazillion hits on the pilot's handbook but *airport information board* will get you the board, and we call the map which states *You are here* a directory... Maybe I'm wrong. I'll let someone else take this, if that's ok.

Comment: @Susan: Could the word you're thinking of for theaters be a [marquee](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/marquee) (def 1.2.b)? (I never knew it had that many definitions!)

Comment: @dingo_dan - No, that's the big illuminated sign over the door. :( I feel helpless tonight.

Comment: I've enjoyed many of your questions in the last few days, but I wonder how you are coming across so many interesting and varied topics.  Are you reading/writing a book?  Studying for a course?  Planning a rather extensive trip to America?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've actually asked about several different types of signage in your question.

If you are asking about a building with a sign directing you to various floors or offices, then this *is* called a **building directory**.  Oddly, I cannot find a dictionary definition for this use either.  [But, here is a company that makes electronic versions of them.](http://www.electronicbuildingdirectory.com/?gclid=CKjD95ni97wCFeJF7Aodt3wACw)

If you are speaking of a sign that tells airport departure or arrival times, gates, flight info, this is called a **board**.  (*e.g.* Departure Board)  You could make a case to refer to this as a directory, but most airports call this the *board* or *information board*.

If you are speaking of a board that tells you theatre times, then this is called a **theatre schedule board**.  I don't know that this is a formal name for it, but that's what I've always called it.

And, for anything that hangs on a wall or for a ceiling that tells you where you are going, you can always use the catch-all **sign** to describe this.