# Name of display with moving lights used in supermarkets and filling stations

Tags: phrase-requests, nouns

What do you call a box like object containing little light bulbs, that when switched on displays moving words. It is commonly used by filling stations, supermarkets etc.,.

Comment: possible dupe; ["directory for the main board..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155269/directory-for-the-main-board-in-an-airport-etc-informing-people-on-arrivals)

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate question as this is about moving words, not a board full of information being updated or a directory.  I suppose he could elaborate more to make it clear that the words are moving left to right across the screen and that there is more information than is on display at any given time looping through or being updated periodically into the loop.

Answer (score 6):

Ticker display may be a better term than marquee.

Comment: Yes.  http://www.electronicsigns.com/ticker.htm

Answer (score 3):

A marquee display is close to what you ask but does not necessarily move.